# Create readable image dataset for training in Keras

Tags: dataset, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to create my own image recognition program with help of keras, but I have encounter a problem. I am trying to take the folder(s) with pictures and create a dataset for the `model.fit()` to use. I am aware of the `fit_generator()` but trying to know what the generator does with the images. Thats why I am manuely trying to create an array/dataset of numbers from images.

**The model I am using is the VGG16, so this is the end and beginning of that model:**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), input_shape=(256, 256, 3)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
...
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

**Compiler:**

```
sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy')
```

**fit:**

```
model.fit(test_x, 1, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=10, verbose=1, callbacks=None, validation_split=0.1)
```

**Array generator:**

```
path_temp = %PATH%

list = os.listdir(path_temp)
array_list = []

for file in list:

    img = imread(path_temp + '\\' + file, flatten=True)
    img = np.arange(1 * 3 * 256 * 256).reshape((-1, 256, 256, 3))

    img = img.astype('float32')
    array_list.append(img)

test_x = np.stack(array_list)
test_x /= 255.0
```

**ERROR:**

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected zeropadding2d_input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (990, 1, 256, 256, 3)
```

This is what i have, but is there some way from here to create a readable dataset/array for the `fit()`?

Comment: Have you read my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the code provided in your `for` loop:

```
for file in list:

    img = imread(path_temp + '\\' + file, flatten=True)
    img = np.arange(1 * 3 * 256 * 256).reshape((256, 256, 3))
    # img = np.array(img).reshape((256, 256, 3)) <- consider this

    img = img.astype('float32')
    array_list.append(img)
```

First problem came from the fact that you were stacking images together - so there was no need to add *sample* dimension in `reshape`. Second thing - is that you are reading `img` from file and then you are erasing it by creating a completely new `np.array` using `np.arange` function. Was that intended or not? If not - check the code snippet I provided.